# Problem with reading multiple potentiometer values on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, potentiometer

I'm working on an Arduino sketch that will read in values from two potentiometers. The code for this is below:

```
int lastPotentiometerOneValue = 0;
int lastPotentiometerTwoValue = 0;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 57600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {
  delay(10);
  readAndSendPotentiometerDataIfChanged();
}

void readAndSendPotentiometerDataIfChanged(void) {

  //Potentiometer One
  int newPotentiometerOneValue = analogRead(A0) / 10.2;   
  if (newPotentiometerOneValue == lastPotentiometerOneValue) return;

  Serial.print("!pos1");
  Serial.print(newPotentiometerOneValue);
  Serial.print(";");
  lastPotentiometerOneValue = newPotentiometerOneValue;

  //Potentiometer Two
  int newPotentiometerTwoValue = analogRead(A1) / 10; 
  if (newPotentiometerTwoValue == lastPotentiometerTwoValue) return;

  Serial.print("!pos2");
  Serial.print(newPotentiometerTwoValue);
  Serial.print(";");
  lastPotentiometerTwoValue = newPotentiometerTwoValue;
}
```

The schematic for my circuit is below (I've left out the code for reading the state of the push-button in my listing above, as that's in a separate method from the method that reads in the potentiometer data):

[image]

However, there seems to be a rather subtle error I'm experiencing. If I turn Potentiometer One, it will display the correct output in the serial monitor. If I turn Potentiometer Two, no value will be displayed. *However*, if I remove Potentiometer Two from the circuit board and turn Potentiometer One, then the serial monitor will display the Potentiometer Two as having the same data as Potentiometer Two.

I'm sure the problem is with my circuit, but I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have some insight? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that if the value for pot1 has not changed, the value for pot2 will never be sent, even if it has changed, due to the early return when checking the value of pot1. You could fix this by changing to:

```
void readAndSendPotentiometerDataIfChanged(void) {

  //Potentiometer One
  int newPotentiometerOneValue = analogRead(A0) / 10.2;   
  if (newPotentiometerOneValue != lastPotentiometerOneValue) {
      Serial.print("!pos1");
      Serial.print(newPotentiometerOneValue);
      Serial.print(";");
      lastPotentiometerOneValue = newPotentiometerOneValue;
  }

  //Potentiometer Two
  int newPotentiometerTwoValue = analogRead(A1) / 10.2; 
  if (newPotentiometerTwoValue != lastPotentiometerTwoValue) {
      Serial.print("!pos2");
      Serial.print(newPotentiometerTwoValue);
      Serial.print(";");
      lastPotentiometerTwoValue = newPotentiometerTwoValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked beautifully! I realized that I was looking at a rather old code example that was based off of only one potentiometer (where those "return" statements came from).